# How to access a variable info via iterators

Tags: bash, variables, for-loop

I am trying to access the value of a bash variable within a for loop. I am doing something like this:

```
A="a"
B="b"
C="c"
VARIABLES=( A B C )

for i in "${VARIABLES[@]}"
do
   ...
   ... 
   ...
done
```

How could i access the value of the variable? (Something like `$$i`?)

Comment: What you're looking for is called an "indirect reference" in bash: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ivr.html. I would post this as an answer, but this is almost certainly a duplicate question.

Comment: That's a problem with Stack Overflow: it's difficult to find a good duplicate even when you *know* the issue and the solution, let alone if you are the one asking the question.

Answer (score 2):

Just use [indirection](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#indirection):

```
$ A=a B=b C=c
$ for i in A B C; do echo "${!i}"; done
a
b
c
```